# Creating Ruby Main (command line utility) program with multiple files

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use the [`main`](https://github.com/ahoward/main) gem for making command line utilities. This was presented in a recent Ruby Rogues podcast.

If I put all the code in one file and require that file, then rspec gives me an error, as the main dsl regards rpsec as a command line invocation of the main utility.

I can break out a method into a new file and have rspec require that file. Suppose you have this program, but want to put the `do_something` method in a separate file to test with rspec:

```
require 'main'

def do_something(foo)
  puts "foo is #{foo}"
end    

Main {
  argument('foo'){
    required                    # this is the default
    cast :int                   # value cast to Fixnum
    validate{|foo| foo == 42}   # raises error in failure case 
    description 'the foo param' # shown in --help
  }
  do_something(arguments['foo'].value)   
}
```

What is the convenient way to distribute/deploy a ruby command line program with multiple files? Maybe create a gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track for testing - basically you want your "logic" in separate files so you can unit test them.  You can then use something like [Aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba) to do an integration test.

With multiple files, your best bet is to distribute it as a RubyGem.  There's lots of resources out there, but the gist of it is:

- Put your executable in `bin`
- Put your files in `lib/YOUR_APP/whatever.rb` where "YOUR_APP" is the name of your app.  I'd also recommend namespacing your classes with modules named for your app
- In your executable, require the files in `lib` as if `lib` were in the load path
- In your gemspec, make sure to indicate what your bin files are and what your lib files are (if you generate it with `bundle gem` and are using git, you should be good to go)

This way, your app will have access to the files in `lib` at runtime, *when installed with RubyGems*.  In development, you will need to either do `bundle exec bin/my_app` or `RUBYLIB=lib bin/my_app`.  Point is, RubyGems takes care of the load path at runtime, but not at development time.